# Backbone: adding models to a collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections, view, addition, repeat

On the one hand, i have three CollectionsView (three types of models fetched from the server), on the other hand i have a quarter CollectionView that works like a shopping cart. This stores items from the other three Collections associated with the views (Collections Views).

The problem is when i add a item with the same id this is edited, not added to the Shopping cart CollectionView.

Example:

```
function addToCart(model){
     ShoppingCartCollectionView.collection.add(model);
}
```

From the others collections:

```
// From one CollectionView
addToCart(this.model);

// From another CollectionView
addToCart(this.model);
```

This Collections have the same id because they are stored in diferent databases on the server.

This is my model (Python ORM)

```
PRODUCT_TYPE = (
    ('EM', 'Empanada'),
    ('BE', 'Bebida'),
    ('OF', 'Oferta'),
)

# Create your models here.
class Producto(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    precio_unidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Empanada(Producto):

    precio_docena = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE, default='EM', editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Bebida(Producto):

    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE, default='BE', editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Oferta(Producto):
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE, default='OF', editable=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Venta(models.Model):

    pedido = models.TextField()
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How to solve this?

THANKS !!!

Comment: Are you sure that your db structure is correctly set up? It seems to me that products from a `products` database will all have a unique id (PK). When having different types of products, you just create a FK to indicate the product_type; you don't need three different tables for that...

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edited the post with adding my database. Yes,is redundant but one product have attributes that others do not. Another pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KimGysen is right about looking into restructuring your products tables. Having different products with the same `id` is going to cause you problems in the long run. Here's a database schema that may work for you.

### Using foreign key tables

First you'd have a product name table where you'd list the name of your different products and assign each product type a primary key (ID). Then, group the different attributes of your product and make a separate table for each group. In the table you'd refer to your original product types by their ID (this is your foreign key). Here's a simple diagram:

```js
/*Name Table                             Prod Type 1
-------------------------------        ---------------------------------
| ID | Product Name | Prod Type        | ProdId | attr1 | ... |  attrN |
-------------------------------        ---------------------------------
| 1  | Product 1    |    1    |        |    1   | val1  | ... | valN   |
-------------------------------        ---------------------------------*/
```

### Work with or around `collection.set`

Your other option is to override the `collection.set` method in Backbone, which is responsible for identifying whether there are duplicates in your set.

#### Cheating `collection.set`

If you're having problems because your adding two different types of products with the same id you can cheat `collection.set` by making sure that their `id` attribute is called something other than `id` (this is what set uses to evaluate whether you have to identical models in your collection, unless you tell it to check a different property by setting the `idAttribute` property in your model definition). Then `collection.set` will not know how to match incoming models.

#### Overriding `collection.set`

If you're having trouble because `collection.set` is not storing a model that is already in your collection, then you will have to override `collection.set`. Let me know if this is the fix you're looking for and I'll post that answer here.

### Create a new `ShoppingCart` Model

A third possibility is to have a ShoppingCart model that handles the addition and removal of models. This is a more complicated solution. If you provide more details about how your cart is being used I can drop a few ideas on how to get your started.

Comment: Thanks!
I solved the problem by restructuring the database and then modifying the serializer and viewSets from django rest framework.

AGAIN, THANKS !!!!

Comment: That's probably the best way to go. When I started this answer post I wrote several lines showing you how to override `collection.set`, and as i did it became clear that having different products with the same id would cause you headaches in the future (Backbone hours or of its way to ensure you don't have dupes in your collection). I realized @Kim Gysen really had the best advice and simply showed you how to implement it. Glad it's working for you!